# Electrical conductivity of metals on heating

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, metals

What effect does heating have on metals (to be specific, on the electrical conductivity) ? And why does it have that effect?

Comment: Could you be more specific what you want to know about that?

Comment: That list of effects would easily fill a full semester of solid state physics. You need to be a little more selective than that.

Answer (score 1):

> **What effect [does] heating have on [the electrical conductivity of] metals?**

Conductivity drops as temperature rises

See [How Does Temperature Affect the Conductivity of a Conductor?](http://fog.ccsf.cc.ca.us/~wkaufmyn/ENGN45/Course%20Handouts/15_ElectricalProps/05_TemperatureConductivityConductor.html)

[image]
<sup>Note, this graph plots resistivity not conductivity, vs temperature.</sup>

Temperature obviously affects the thermal velocity of free electrons and this affects the rate of collisions. This affects drift velocity and hence current.

Obviously, sufficient heating to cause a change of phase would likely have a more dramatic effect on electrical conductivity.